# Is this is the best way to write SQL for this report?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, group-by

We have `orders` data and we need to generate `Weekly - Custom date Range of 7 Days`report using `SQL`. The report will display weekly `count` of Orders. The user will select an `End Date` and we need to create 12 DateRange units based on that date. For example the user selects `1/24/2013` we need 12 Points/Units as:

```
Point12 = End Date - 7 Days
Point11 = End Date - 14 Days
Point10 = End Date - 21 Days
Point9  = End Date - 28 Days
.
.
Point1  = End Date - X Days
```

**Our solution**:

We are planning to create a temporary table that table will have 12 Rows. Each row will have data like (we will calculate the startdate and endDate for each Point):

```
Point   StartDate           EndDate      TotalOrders
Point12  2013-01-24          2013-01-30   
Point11  2013-01-17          2013-01-23
```

After this we will get the `count` of Orders for each row.

**Is this is a good solution to this problem or it can be optimized?**

**EDIT:**

The weekly DateRange will be a `Custom date Range of 7 Days`.

[image]

Comment: @EdHeal: I can do it by myself. but i just want to know that i am doing it in the best possible way.

Comment: in this scenario you should use Table variable for better performance.  You can read this article about difference: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/temp-tables-vs-variables/

Comment: How are you getting the `count` for each row?

Comment: Looping through all 12 rows in the table and using `SELECT COUNT` WHERE `OrderDate >= @StartDateOfThatRow` and `OrderDate <= @`EndDateOfThatRow`

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi - That article contains myths such as  transaction logs are not recorded for the table variables. See [my answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386) for a more accurate summary. The reason why the results are better for table variables with small numbers of rows [is explained here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/why-is-using-a-table-variable-more-than-twice-as-fast-as-a-temp-table-in-this-s)

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is SQLServer, I suggest using a table variable, rather than a temporary table.

An alternative approach would be to generate the 12 rows in a CTE as part of the main query, rather than generating the required rows (in a table variable/temporary table) as a separate step prior to the main query. This would reduce the total number of steps required, but would make the main query slightly more complicated.

Comment: What rationale for the advice "I suggest using a table variable, rather than a temporary table."? I don't necessarily disagree but you should state the benefit you believe will be gained.

Comment: That is a myth. Both table variables and `#temp` tables are held in `tempdb` and both of them would be likely to be have all the pages in memory for a table that small.

Comment: See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx

Comment: What part of it? It doesn't support your claim at all?

Comment: The section that begins: "table variables provide the following benefits for small-scale queries that have query plans that do not change"

Comment: Which is not at all related to your claim of "memory only" vs tempdb. One possible advantage of table variables is indeed fewer recompiles  (can also be a disadvantage if the recompile would give a better plan) but that wasn't your argument.

Comment: Which I removed, before I posted the link to the MSDN article. Are you deliberately trolling?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24616/discussion-between-mark-bannister-and-martin-smith)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't just use the week as grouping factor?

```
SELECT
 WEEKOFYEAR(`date`) AS point,
 SUM(orders) AS order
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN `startdate` AND `enddate`
GROUP BY point
```